# Dynamic IP whitelist based on txt file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

We want our website to be accessed only by few IP's, we listed those IP's in txt file and our server is Apache. Can any one please give a solution for this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic! For server software and hardware related stuff, please visit https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

i propose you to work over the router or firewall that is hosting your site
you can generate an .acl files with the IP'S and create a rules that will allow traffic just for the ip'S listed in the files.
www.countryipblocks.net/acl.php1

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this question is off-topic on here and will probably be deleted.